# Show the differential operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, differential-operators

I need to show the differential operator is bounded. I believe it is bounded on $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm by 1, but I am struggling to show this. What I have so far:
NTS: $\|Tf\|\leq\|T\|\|f\|$ Where:

\begin{equation} \|Tf\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f'(x)|=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \left|\frac{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right|
\end{equation}

Not entirely sure if I should have written the derivative like that in the last equality above. I need a hint to see where to go next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 16):

**Hint**: Denote by
$$D:(C^{1}[0,1],\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})\rightarrow(C[0,1],\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$$
the differential operator. Let $f_{n}(x)=\sin(nx)$. Note that $\Vert f_{n}\Vert_{\infty}=1$ (for $n\geq 2$). However, $(Df_{n})(x)=n\cos(nx)$, and hence $\Vert Df_{n}\Vert_\infty=n$. What does this mean?

Comment: This means that.... since we are considering the sup for $x\in [0,1]$, so $\|f'\|=1$ ... correct? But does this tell me that it is bounded for any function?

Comment: Incorrect. What is $f$? I only defined $f_n$, and I showed that $\Vert Df_n \Vert = n$ (not $1$). I was hinting that the differential operator is *not* bounded. In fact, it's a classic example of an unbounded operator.

Comment: So $f_n$ does not converge...right? And therefore cannot be bounded. I think I understand now, thank you!

Comment: Sort of, but not quite. Here is the argument. The operator norm is (by definition) $\Vert D\Vert=\sup_{\Vert f\Vert=1}\Vert Df\Vert$.
We say $D$ is bounded if its operator norm is finite. Suppose $D$
is bounded. Then, for any sequence $(f_{n})_{n}$ with $\Vert f_{n}\Vert=1$ for each $n$,
it follows that $\Vert Df_{n}\Vert\leq\Vert D\Vert$. However, I showed
you a sequence for which $\Vert Df_{n}\Vert\rightarrow\infty$. Contradiction.

Comment: @parsiad, if we define the differential operator in a closed subspace or a finite-dimensional closed sub-space, then the operator is bounded? I am hesitating since the operator norm is usually defined in a more general Banach space, not necessarily finite.

Answer (score -3):

What about the effect of differentiating a sequence f sub n = sin(2pi* n* x) where n is integer > 0?

You get 2pi *n *cosine, whose supremum is infinite